# What causes Kill state issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have been getting the following error for over a year:

[image]

This is happening in one of my sql databases. I have been searching online but nothing has helped. Some sources say this error is caused by index corruption but it doesn't seem to be the case.

This is what I have been doing in the last 12 months, whenever I get this error. I restore a fresh db and it works for about a week then the error pops up again. I am considering moving form a VM to a physical server.

Any ideas?

Comment: It can be data corruption, or it can be that the query is executing under low-privileged user while someone sets db to restricted user. Did you check your db with dbcc checkdb?

Comment: There is a similar post, have a look https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154465/cannot-continue-the-execution-because-the-session-is-in-the-kill-state-while-bu

Comment: What SQL Server version?  When does this error happen?  Do you see any patterns?

Comment: @tukan am on SQL 2016 version. the error happens when I run processes from a SOFTWARE APP

Comment: **Did you check your db with dbcc checkdb?**

Comment: @sepupic I have run the dbcc checkdb command and here is the results:


Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: So your database is corrupted

Comment: @sepupic but I have restored a new fresh db

Comment: You restored it from a backup of corrupted database

Comment: @immortal you have to corrupted backup - try running `DBCC CHECKDB <database_name> REPAIR_REBUILD` what is the result there?

Comment: @tukan The result will be the same error. Metadata is corrupted so dbcc checkdb cannot procede at all

Comment: @sepupic then your only option is to perform "last resort" option `DBCC CHECKDB <database_name> REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` which will most likely lead to data loss (it will warn you which data you are to lose).  (Don't forget to run `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS` after the repair).  You can read more at *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql*.   For next time remember when DB gives you such an error to handle it immediately and not after one year.

Comment: @tukan First of all I'm NOT author of this topic, I don't have any corrupted database and I regularly porform dbcc checkdb prior to backup, so my backups do not contain corrupted databases at all, that is different from OP that has backuped corrupted database even without noting it. Second and the most important: your "last resort" won't work, the error will be the same

Comment: Here is Paul Randal's article that describes in what situation dbcc cannot repair a database (Randal is the person who wrote dbcc checkbd for SQL Server 2005), and be sure that the error that OP got is one of those, even worse. Here is the article: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-can-checkdb-repair-everything/

Comment: @sepupic Then you should tell the one who is responsible for this.  If the last resort does not work then you have to extract the data manually.

Comment: @sepupic Thank you guys for detailed information. What I have just discovered is that, If I restore the same db over to a different server and run the DBCC Checkdb again, I dont get that error. Seems like its a hardware problem. So we are going to to move everything to a new server and see what happens. Seems like there problem is with the VM we are using

Comment: @tukan, I still cannot understand why do you think that the question is MINE. I repeat, I am NOT Immortal (author of this question)

Comment: @Immortal, Good news, this means that your backup contains database that is not corrupted, all you need now is to check your disks where you restored first and where the error occurs. For the future, create a job that at least once a week (maybe on Sunday) does check db of all databases

Comment: @sepupic Its a bit confusing sometimes for example, I executed c:\>chkdsk but never got any suspicious result. If the problem is my hardware i.e. drives etc, wasn't I suppose to pick this up when running the chkdsk in command line?

Comment: I think it's disk bad sector, or something similar, not driver problem. There are vendor's utilities for disks, don't you have one of them?

Comment: @sepupic sorry got it mixed in the thread.  That was meant for Immortal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the VM to a new physical server